# isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) return false

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-location

I am using `NETWORK_PROVIDER` to get `latitude` and `longitude` of the place.

I'v already check the setting in the "location & security" and enable "use wireless networks". But `"isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)"` always return `false`.

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Here is my code :

```
LocationManager locManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean isEnableGPS=locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
boolean isEnableNTW=locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
Log.d(TAG, isEnableGPS+", "+isEnableNTW);
```

permission in the AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: you testing on Emulator? If yes, it wont work.

Comment: Oh, I frogot to mention...I use my cell phone.

Comment: Same here

  isGPSEnabled = this.myLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

Always returns false.

Answer (score 13):

Make sure that network based location is enabled in the phone's settings. You can detect this situation and prompt the user to enable it if you really need it.

I believe this is the line of code to launch this activity.

```
activity.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
```

[ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)

This article explains it http://emobiledude.com/fix-waiting-for-location-in-google-maps-after-android-4-2-update/

[image: Android 4.0 Location Access Settings]