# network provider of location manager is unavailable

Tags: android, location

The following code always print false

```
this.locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Log.d(TAG, "network provider enabled: " + locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));
```

The permissions have been required include:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

In `Settings`, all the location switches has been turned to allowed.
Then, why is the network provider unavailable?

**Update:**
The same code prints true on a Samsung Galaxy device, a Google Nexus device(Nexus 4) and a Lenovo device, but false on a Motorola Droid device(Droid Boinic with CM11) and a Sony device. In "Settings", all the location switches have been turned to allowed on those devices.
Seems like device or OS issue.

Comment: [Check once](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25617657) if google's location service option is checked or not

Comment: Also please restart your device once to make reflect of your changes

Comment: I've read that answer, and the google's location service is already allowed. Restart doesn't work.

Comment: I think you are testing this in emulator that's why this return false.Try to test in a real device.

Comment: The code prints false on Motorola XT875 with CM 11, and a Sony Xperia phone.